# How to calculate total weight of columns with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a weight calculator for a list of products. But, I am having problem to calculate and display the sum total.

I am having the problem where I call the function GeneralTotalWeight() at the bottom. I think it doesnt get triggered.

this is the screenshot of the html. I marked the label with yellow.

[image]

here is the html.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="article in articles">
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="article.size" class="form-control" placeholder="Ölçü" min=0 disabled>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="article.name" class="form-control" placeholder="Ürün" min=0 disabled>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" ng-model="article.quantity" class="form-control bfh-number" step=1>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label ng-model="article.meter" class="form-control bfh-number" style="width:150px" disabled>
                {{article.quantity*6}}
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" ng-model="article.weight" class="form-control bfh-number" min=0 disabled>
        </td>
        <td>
            @*<input type="number" ng-model="article.totalWeight" class="form-control bfh-number" min=0 disabled>*@
            <label ng-model="article.totalWeight" class="form-control bfh-number" style="width:150px" disabled>
                {{article.quantity*6*article.weight}}
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="success">
        <td class="success">TOPLAM</td>
        <td class="success"></td>
        <td ng-model="article.totalQuantityX" class="success">{{ GeneralTotalQuantity() }} Boy</td>
        <td class="success">{{ GeneralTotalMeter() }} metre</td>
        <td class="success"></td>
        <td ng-model="article.totalWeightX" class="success">{{ GeneralTotalWeight() | number:2 }} KG</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

the code is below...

```
$scope.GeneralTotalWeight = function () {
    var resultWeight = 0;

    angular.forEach($scope.articles, function (article) {
        resultWeight += article.totalWeight * article.meter;
    });
    return resultWeight;
};
```

How can I fix this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use expression and ng-model at a same time. Remove ng-model from it. and pass articles directly in your function

```
 <td class="success">{{ GeneralTotalWeight(articles) | number:2 }} KG</td>
```

and function should be like

```
$scope.GeneralTotalWeight = function (articles) {
    var resultWeight = 0;

    angular.forEach(articles, function (article) {
        resultWeight += article.totalWeight * article.meter;
    });
    return resultWeight;
};
```